# Program can't see an object in an "if" method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a program which solves a function with parameters. First we input our values and use an `if` method to give to `s` object value. After that we should give it to our statement `z = 1 - s` and print the result. I'll put an image with my function. The problem is, that my program can't see `s` object. `z = 1 - s NameError: name 's' is not defined`. What should I do?
[image: Our function]

```
import math
x, l, r, a, c = float(input('x: ')), float(input('l: ')), float(input('r: ')), float(input('a: ')), 
float(input('c: '))

if x <= 1:
    s = 0
elif l < x < (l + r) / 2:
    s = 2 * math.pow(( x - l) / (r - l), 2)
elif x > r:
    s = 1
elif (l + r) / 2 < x <= r:
    s = 1 - 2 * math.pow((r - x) / (r - l), 2)


z = 1 - s

if x <= c:
    print(s)
elif x > c:
    print(z)
```

Comment: define variable s as empty in starting, there's no s in starting scope so the locally available s is not avaliable In outside scope!! Write in start of code ***s=0***

Comment: Your `if ... elif` construct lacks an `else` at the end. Are you sure that your cases are exhaustive?

Comment: If `s` was not defined, that means none of your `if` or `elif` cases evaluated to `True`. Try stepping through using a debugger to confirm your calculations (by hand) match those you coded up.

Comment: I would step through it in order to see the output of each variable.

My first thought is, that `s` is undefined due to it being local to each if statement.

I would at the very least use methods.

Try defining `S = 0` at the beginning of your logic.

Comment: The formula says ``x <= l``, not ``x <= 1`` as in your code.

Comment: @Agent_Orange, @Paul_Jay - the scope is fine; in Python, `if` blocks do not introduce their own scope, so `s` will be available outside, provided at least one of the `if`/`elif` conditions matched (or there was an `else` clause which also defined `s`).

Comment: @sabik alright, new knowledge everyday, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `if`/`elif`/`elif` statement doesn't have an `else` clause; if none of the conditions match, none of the branches will be taken.

  To see if this is a problem, add an `else` clause (perhaps a simple one to signal an error).
- In your first condition you write `x <= 1` (eks less than or equal to one), but I think the formula is `x <= l` (eks less than or equal to ell).

Try it like this:

```
if x <= l:  # changed 1 to l
    s = 0
elif l < x < (l + r) / 2:
    s = 2 * math.pow(( x - l) / (r - l), 2)
elif x > r:
    s = 1
elif (l + r) / 2 < x <= r:
    s = 1 - 2 * math.pow((r - x) / (r - l), 2)
else:  # added else clause
    raise ValueError(f"Unexpected values: x={x}, l={l}, r={r}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are cases that don't yield `True` in any of the four if statements.

In particular I think the first if statement is wrong, instead of `<= 1` the picture seems to say `<= l`.

Comment: Good catch with the `1` vs. `l`. Further evidence that it is almost always a bad idea to use `l` as a variable

Answer (score 0):

`s` is created in the conditional blocks. If `s` does not exist after your first `if` clause block, then none of its conditions evaluated to true and subsequently `s` was initialized.

Either add an `else` statement at the end of the first `if` block or make sure that your input always leads to one of the `if`/`elif` conditions matching.

Answer (score 0):

*s* is defined in the first conditional loop, so if it's not defined is because the algorithm hasn't found a true condition. Based on the current loop, if x>1 & x<l, then *s* is not defined.

Comment: Also if x>r then s is not defined.